# SQL How can I get the first two digits in a column?

Tags: sql, oracle

**The question is** "For every customer, list the customer number, the customer entire zip code, and add two more columns where the next column is the first 2 numbers of the zip code, and the last column is the last 3 numbers of the zip code."

**and I wrote**

```
SELECT CUST_CUSTOMER_NUMBER, CUST_ZIP_CODE,LEFT(CUST_ZIP_CODE,2) AS ZIP_1
FROM CUSTOMER
```

but it keeps showing :

[image]

Comment: Use `SUBSTR()` in Oracle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT CUST_CUSTOMER_NUMBER, CUST_ZIP_CODE,SUBSTR(CUST_ZIP_CODE,1,2) AS ZIP_1
FROM CUSTOMER
```

Format for using SUBSTR

`SUBSTR( string, start_position [, length ] )`